# Index was outside the bounds of the array in CheckedListBox

Tags: c#

I am getting an index error on my else if statement but I'm unable to find the reason for it.

What I am doing is going through a `CheckedListBox`, if no values are checked print an error else show the selected values in a `MessageBox`.

Can anybody help me? Thank you!

```
for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
if (checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count == 0) 
{
  Empty.SetError(checkedListBox1, "Please select at Least One");
  return;
}
else if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i))
{
   MessageBox.Show(checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[i].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `Count`-ckeck before the loop:

```
 if (checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count == 0)
 {
    Empty.SetError(checkedListBox1, "Please select at Least One");
    return;
 }
```

But the important part is that you are looping **all** items. Then you check for every item if it is checked with [`GetItemChecked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.getitemchecked(v=vs.110).aspx). That's fine, but then you use [`checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[i]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems(v=vs.110).aspx) which doesn't contain *all* items but only the **checked** items. That's why you get the *Index was outside the bounds* error.

Instead you just need to use that collection instead of looping all:

```
for(int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
{
    MessageBox.Show(checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[i].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change

```
i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count;
```

To:

```
i < checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count;
```

Comment: That's not enough `checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i)` will give wrong results then. -1

Answer (score 1):

`checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[i]` is the problem. You loop through all the items, but indexing `CheckedItems`. So when you have 10 items and checked 2nd item and 8th item, `CheckedItems` will have only two items but you'll be accessing `CheckedItems[7]` that's why you get the exception.

Use `CheckedItems` collection to access checked items directly.

```
if (checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count == 0)
{
    Empty.SetError(checkedListBox1, "Please select at Least One");
    return;
}
foreach (var checkedItem in checkedListBox1.CheckedItems)
{
    MessageBox.Show(checkedItem.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you checking for CheckedItems.Count inside the for cycle?

Take the first part of the If clause outside of the For cycle.

At the end your code can look like that:

```
 if (checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count == 0)
 {
    Empty.SetError(checkedListBox1, "Please select at Least One");
 }
 for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
   if (checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i))
   {
     MessageBox.Show(checkedListBox1.Items[i].ToString());
   }
```

Comment: Does this prevent the exception?

Comment: This will allow the second part of the if to work correctly. It will check every single "i" element from the checkedListBox.

Comment: Also there is no point to use CheckedItems[i] if the "i" item is checked from the list. You can take it with checkedListBox1.Items[i].ToString();